# Getting JSON object from URL using JS

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get a JSON object from a URL using only JavaScript no JQuery
this is the JSON object I'm trying to get (the source of the page):

```
{"projects":[{"id":"38","name":"Sample Nursing Program Development"},{"id":"39","name":"test"},{"id":"40","name":"Sree"},{"id":"42","name":"NUR 521 edit"},{"id":"44","name":"Sree"}]}
```

and my Javascript code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  function getJSONP(url, success) {
    var ud = '_' + +new Date,
    script = document.createElement('script'),
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement;

    window[ud] = function(data) {
      head.removeChild(script);
      success && success(data);
    };

    script.src = url.replace('callback=?', 'callback=' + ud);
    head.appendChild(script);
  }

  function myFunction() { 
    getJSONP('..url', function(data) {
      var  obj = JSON.parse(data);
      var listItems= "";
      alert("hello");
      for (var i = 0; i < obj.projects.length; i++) {
        listItems+= "<option value='" + obj.projects[i].id + "'>" + obj.projects[i].name + "</option>";
      }
      $("#mainProject").html(listItems);
    });  
  }
</script>
```

I'm using getJSONP to get the JSON object and using myFunction to populate a list with the data in the JSON object, but unfortunately I'm getting nothing in the list, can you help me locate the error please?

Comment: Not only you are bypassing JQuery, but you are also bypassing AJAX. Any reason you want to do it like this? I think it's a creative solution, but if you follow this path then you might also want to check the debugger tools (F12) to see if there are any script errors and if the request is fired at all.

Comment: either way I think here `})` needs to be a `;`. And I too am surprised and would definately suggest you use jQuery. I was so agains it before I fully started using it, but seeing this just reminds me how happy I am I finally did give it a chance

Comment: and I would make a global function (`function loadJsonResponse()` or something) of that success function. You are now passing along that whole function to getJSONP(). That is so weird, and if it works the way I imagine it to, also very ineffecient

Comment: in fact I'm getting SyntaxError: missing ; before statement, even after I added the ; after the })